# Unable to create new labor detail row in Epicor customization

Tags: c#, customization, epicorerp

i am doing Epicor customization , i tried to create new row in labor detail table , but it came out this error
[image]

```
   LaborAdapter adapterLabor = new LaborAdapter(this.oTrans);
        adapterLabor.BOConnect();
//adapterLabor.GetNewLaborDtl(1109);
bool resultGetNewLaborDtl = adapterLabor.GetNewLaborDtlAttch(1111,217588);;
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(resultGetNewLaborDtl.ToString(), "Done");
```

Comment: the message is clear, one of your number doesn't exist in the database already, a foreign key restarint will every time chekc if the data you entered exist uin the referenced table. and you should try catch such actions

Comment: Company EmployeeNum LaborHedSeq LaborDtlSeq
STRAITS SE3260 1111 217588
but this is exist in my labordtl table

Comment: we can not helpo you as we don't know your structure and constraints, if the databse tells you that it isn't there, then it is usually right. error message must be in text to see the complete error message,

Answer (score 0):

Method call `.GetNewLaborDtlAttch(1111,217588)` is attempting to add a record for LaborHedSeq `1111` and LaborDtlSeq `217588` which has already been previously saved to the database and cannot be a duplicate in the current session company.

Based on your note that you are trying to create a new labor detail record, here are some additional issues to point out that should help on your way:

1. `LaborDtlAttch` is not the same as `LaborDtl` and can be used when a `LaborDtl` already exists.
2. `LaborAdapter` is an `IDisposable`. It is important to wrap this in a using or implement a finally/dispose paradigm to prevent memory leaks.
3. Adapters store local information in the client which is not written back to the server unless an `Update()` method is called.
4. Classic UI customizations are deprecated. Consider simplifying the code used in the customization layer in any required customizations and have any logic that is not related directly to display to be handled using server-side methods, which will still work the same way using the Kinetic UI.

Here is an updated sample of code to get started in creating a new laborDtl record.

```
int laborHedSeq = 0;
// TODO Retrieve laborHedSeq from UI or lookup active row as necessary
using(LaborAdapter laborAdapter = new LaborAdapter(this.oTrans))
{
    laborAdapter.BOConnect();   
    laborAdapter.GetNewLaborDtl(laborHedSeq);
    Erp.BO.LaborDataSet.LaborDtlRow laborDtl = laborAdapter.LaborData.LaborDtl[laborAdapter.LaborData.LaborDtl.Count - 1];
    // TODO Edit additional fields of the new laborDtl row here
    laborAdapter.Update();
}
```